# Jquery mobile app works on the desktop, doesnt work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem, I am making a jquery mobile web app for android, and on one page I cant fire button "Proveri" on mobile devices(iPhone 5 and Asus Pad HD 7 tested).

The link is [here](http://domaceserije.org/FCK/1nivo/1.html)

Chek HTML on the source code of this page.

JS:

> ```
>            var film = new Array("balkan ekspres","balkan expres");
>
>   $(document).ready(function() {
>       $('.pomoc').hide();
>       if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
>       {
>           //ucitavanje pomoci
>           $('.btnpomoc').click(function(){
>               $('.pomoc').slideDown();
>           });
>
>
>           $("#bb").text(localStorage.bodovi);
>
>
>           if(localStorage.prviprvo.length>3){
>               $("#imefilma").val(localStorage.prviprvo);
>               $("#proveri").parent('.ui-submit').addClass("ui->disabled");
>               $("#proveri").prev('span.ui-btn->inner').find('span.ui-btn-text').text("Pogođeno");
>           }
>
>           else{
>
>               $(".proveri").on('tap', function(){
>
>                   var imef = >$("#imefilma").val().toLowerCase();
>                   var pogodak;
>                   $.trim(imef);
>
>                   for(i=0;i<=film.length-1;i++){
>
>
>                       if(imef==film[i]){
>                           pogodak = true;
>
>                       }else{
>                           pogodak = false;
>                       }
>                   }
>                   if(pogodak==true){
>
>                       var prvoSlovo  = imef.substr(0,1);
>                       var ostatak = imef.substr(1);
>                       var novoIme =   >prvoSlovo.toUpperCase() + ostatak;
>
>                       $("#imefilma").val(novoIme);
>
>                       alert("Tačno!");
>                       //registrujemo da je ovo pitanje 
>                       localStorage.prviprvo = novoIme;
>
>                       localStorage.bodovi = >Number(localStorage.bodovi) + 10;
>
>                       $("#bb").text(localStorage.bodovi);
>                   }else{
>                       alert("Netačno!");
>
>                   }
>
>
>
>               });
>           }
>       }
>       else
>           alert("Dogodila se greska");
>   });
> ```

Comment: Is it dynamically added? Replace tap with vclick. Also, in JQM, don't use `.ready()`, use JQM events i.e. pageinit, pageshow etc... Edit: it should be `$('#proveri')` not `.proveri` its an id not a class.

Comment: when I put pageinit event the page is not loading, its just shows loading icon.